# JavaFX Dialog returns same result over and over again

Tags: java, javafx, dialog

*Solved: I figured that it isn't a bug of JavaFX, it is made like that on purpose, so you can request the result multiple times from the dialog if you don't wanna save it into a variable. To flush the cache i used setResult(null) on the dialog. That did the job for me :)*

I've created a Dialog to edit/create a Person using JavaFX. But i guess i found a bug. I've added two ButtonType-objects to my dialog. One for saving and one for aborting the actions. When i use those buttons it works just fine. But if i press the 'X' to close the dialog-window, the dialog automaticly returns the last result again. That means if i aborted my last action and in my current one i press 'X' to close the window, the dialog returns no result since the abort-button didn't have one last time. But if i pressed the save-button on my last action and i press 'X' in my current one it returns the same person again, since save-button had this person in its result last time. How can i make the dialog changing to no result on closing?

Here is the action i've created:

```
   this.createPersonAction = new Callback<ButtonType, PersonSession>() {

        @Override
        public PersonSession call(final ButtonType param) {
            if (param.equals(PersonDialogController.this.saveButton)) {
                final String firstName = PersonDialogController.this.firstNameField.getText();
                final String lastName = PersonDialogController.this.lastNameField.getText();
                final Person p = BeanFactory.createPerson(firstName, lastName);
                if (p != null) {
                    return new PersonSession(p);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
```

And here you have my two ButtonType-Objects:

```
private final ButtonType saveButton = new ButtonType(GuiStringRresource.LABEL_SAVE_BUTTON, ButtonData.OK_DONE);
private final ButtonType abortButton = new ButtonType(GuiStringRresource.LABEL_ABORT_BUTTON,
        ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Dialog.setOnCloseRequest` method to handle this case.

Comment: I found a way to solve my problem in a different way. Mentioned it in the edit above. Thanks tho